# eclim - cannot create new Projects

Tags: eclim

I just set up eclim to be used inside (g)vim but it is not working. I can `:PingEclim` so there is no connection Problem but as soon as I try to set up a new Project via
`:ProjectCreate /home/me/projectdir -n cpp"` I get the strange error

`org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Cannot create managed project with NULL configuration`

I am (currently) using Kubuntu 11.04 and gvim.

Answer (score 1):

According to [eclim guide](http://eclim.org/gettingstarted.html) the fix looks pretty simple:

```
:ProjectCreate /home/me/projectdir -n c++
```